# What is the correct way to change the repo on a podspec?

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods

I created my first cocoapod from a personal repo, and deployed it to cocoapods via the pod trunk push command. Since it is my first framework, I wanted to develop it on a personal repo to keep my messy commits private. Now that the product is ready, I need to migrate the work over to an open source repo, and update the cocoapod's source.

I tried changing the s.homepage and s.source lines of the podspec, but I get this `fatal: Remote branch 1.0.0 not found in upstream origin` error.

```sh
Updating spec repo `master`
Validating podspec
 -> EvolvKit (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/evolv-ai/EvolvKit.git /var/folders/jb/xlkpf4sn6fl9wtsh3g7pkqrh0000gp/T/d20190729-87754-7w53ir --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/jb/xlkpf4sn6fl9wtsh3g7pkqrh0000gp/T/d20190729-87754-7w53ir'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 1.0.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 1.0.0 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning.
➜  EvolvKit git:(master)
```

old pod spec:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

# more configs
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/<personal_repo>/EvolvKit'
  s.license          = { :type => 'APACHE', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'PhyllisWong' => 'phyllis.wong@evolv.ai' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/<personal_repo>/EvolvKit.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

# more configs
end
```

The new podspec lines changed:

```rb
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/<opensource_repo>/EvolvKit'
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/<opensource_repo>/EvolvKit.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

Some things I tried are:

```
0. update git tag with version 1.0.0
1. updating the urls in the pod spec
2. clone the repo into a new directory, create a new git repo, and follow steps to trunk push
3. deleting the pod (was only able to delete versions) ...no one is using this pod btw.
4. considered changing the pod name, but that is less than ideal
```

Any ideas about a good way to go forward is greatly appreciated.

*edit*

Turns out I was missing a step in updating my repo with the git tag. Needed to push the tags.

Comment: Did you tag your github release with 1.0.0? If the tag does not align with the expected version, it will fail.

Comment: yes I did update tag. will update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of my above comment about tagging the branch, did you `git push --tags` as well? Applying tags is a two step process, and without both, you can get the above error.

[image]

Comment: Oooof, that was the step I was missing. All is good now, thanks for the help!